# QTooltip with "structured" html

Tags: python, html, qt, pyqt

I have a PyQt6 application that features a custom text editor.
When user hovers some word in this editor, a custom QToolTip is displayed.

I would have liked to make it fancier than the default one, with the following structure:

```
*******        TITLE
*     *
* IMG *  - some text
*     *  - some other text
*******
```

I'm really noobish when it comes to HTML. I tried some code using `<div>` and `<p>` blocks, it delivered what I wanted when loading it in a navigator, but the result was not as expected in the application.

From what it seems, despite the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/richtext-html-subset.html#block-attributes) stating that Qt supports HTML blocks, what I want to achieve might be impossible.

Do you guys have any clue on what I could do to make it work? Above is an example of what I tried.

```
<div style="background-color: #2F3135;font-family: Franklin Gothic;font-size: 12;">
    <div style="float: left;background-color: #2F3135;padding: 30px 20px 30px 30px;"><img src=MY_IMAGE width="64" height="64"/>
    </div>
    <p style="color: #FFFFFF;line-height:135%"><b><span style="background-color: #009900">TITLE:</b></span><br>
        <span style="background-color: #009900;">some text<br></span>
        <span style="background-color: #009900;">some other text<br></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

## EDIT

Following the answer from musicamante, I tried to do a table rather than using div blocks.

As I say in my answer to him, it works except if the title word of the second row is too long. Above should be a reproducable QTooltip example:

```
<table style="background-color: #454850;">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan=7 style="vertical-align: middle;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 15px"><img src=MYIMAGE width="64" height="64"/></th>
    <th><b><span style="color: #CECED7;font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 10;">MAIN_TITLE</span></b></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b><span style="background-color: #307D30;color: #BACABA;font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 10;">Inputs:</b></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span style="background-color: #913131;color: #D0BFBF;font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 10;">blabla</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b><span style="background-color: #913131;color: #D0BFBF;font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 10;">Outputs:</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span style="background-color: #913131;color: #D0BFBF;font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 10;">blabla</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So if **MAIN_TITLE** > 32 characters in my case, the 2nd column will not display properly in the QToolTip.

Maybe I messed up in the HTML code (I'm very new to HTML, never really worked with it).

Any tips is welcomed!

Comment: Just use a simple table.

Comment: Are you confident it works with QToolTip? Gonna check how it works if so.

Comment: OK, I tried it and it worked quite fine although I'm encountering a weird behaviour from the tooltip. Indeed, if the word is too long in the second column (it seems the weird behaviour starts after 32 characters in my case), 2nd column content is display above 1st row content (an image in my case). Probably a limitation from QTooltip... I need to find a work around (I tried to put the too long word on 2 lines but the column size is still messed up for the other content of the column).

I'm going to provide a reproducable example in the main topic.

Comment: Try to keep it simple, that's how real debugging works: reduce the code to the minimum. Don't use table headers, leave out useless divs or empty rows/cells (unless they're needed for the whole layout, which isn't your case). For your layout you only need one row and two cells. This has nothing related to HTML, it's just about basic logic and content hierarchy; don't complicate things: you basically need a left cell for the image, and a right one for the text. Start with that, then fix the alignment of their contents.